Unable to use NPM after installing Node.js. Error message below
I have just installed Node.js in my pc using the .msi installer. I'm using node's latest version (20.14.0). I installed node in order to use NPM to download json-server package. Node seems to be working fine, but i when i use npm in cmd is throws an error message.
`   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module './cli/validate-engines.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:1:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Arthur\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Arthur\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

`
I tried to follow some steps given in another page with a similar error. I uninstalled Node.js, repaired files but nothing worked.

Did you update npm after installation, i.e. npm i -g npm?

@l3l_aze I tried. But when i do it the same error gets me on the way....

Not sure what is the cause but it could be permission issues, which IDK well enough to say anything about on Windows. Have you tried using an alternative installer like nvs - Node Version Switcher or Volta? I had trouble with the default Node installer on Windows too, but NVS worked/works for me.

Some more things to try/check in a similar recent Q.
